# How to fast play Traps/Loot/Hidden treasure

Tags: dnd-5e, treasure, traps

As new players, we ran our first dongeon and the session left me a bitter taste. Some part lasted a long time without being usefull, those parts were when we were searching for treasures or traps.

Indeed, before entering EVERY room the group was : "we look at the door/every tile we step on/wall to determine if there is a hidden trap", and the DM to reply "OK roll for an investigation/perception". And actually there were only one trap for the full dongeon...

Then when we entered a new rom, EVERY player were asking the DM : "I am searching for a hidden treasure/loots/secret door". And the DM, one player at a time : "ok roll", just in order to loot a few pieces from the dead bodies or nothing most of the time...

My questions is : how to manage Traps/Loots/Hidden Treasures without rolling everytime  for everyone and avoiding (as much as possible) to miss a secret door/treasure/hidden trap ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Handling party progression in a dungeon](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/119588/handling-party-progression-in-a-dungeon)

Comment: Also related: [How to deal with players that wants their characters to do automatic perception, stealth and searching for traps/secret doors?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/79439/how-to-deal-with-players-that-wants-their-characters-to-do-automatic-perception?rq=1)

Comment: Welcome to this stack! Take the [tour]. Was this everyone's first tabletop RPG session? Were the session's events discussed afterward? Did anyone else seem bitter? Thank you for participating and have fun!

Comment: A potentially helpful question: "[I want to run vast and realistic dungeons, but my players get frustrated trying to search every room](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/74355)"

Comment: did you and the dm discuss passive investigation and passive perception, per chapter 7?

Comment: @ThomasMarkov, yes for most of the part. However I see two issues when relying on passsive check : 1/ PC may want to roll because the roll can be higher than their passive check (or keep the passive check for their highest PC and roll for the other for a chance to improve); and 2/ if they don't roll, at some point, there is a guaranty that they will ALWAYS fail for a trap/hidden treasure with a check higher thant their passive value (while they may succeed if they roll)

Comment: @KorvinStarmast it could be a solution but as per my other comment, I do see 2 issues in doing that.

Comment: Players can want to roll, but that’s not the rules. Players are supposed to describe what the character would like to do, and the DM adjudicates appropriately. Players in describing character actions should be able to do so without any mention of mechanics.

Comment: When saying they "want the roll", I means that the players will just say to the DM"I am activelly looking at everything" (with the idea behind to be that in that way the player has a chance to improve his passive check) : back to square one.